# C# WinForms Data Binding Argument Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, data-binding

I'm struggling with WinForms data binding. The issue is that the controls should be bound to a model but they just throw `ArgumentException` without any reasonable reason. It's thrown exactly when a `TabPage` shows the control in question. This is the following `Exception.Message`: Unable to link property or Mpn column in DataSource.

So, I can't figure out what's going wrong. It seems to be ok.

It's worth to mention that I'm implementing a "forcing" MVVM to WinForms and the pattern was working fine until now (lol!). I already know that MVVM goes better with WPF and Silverlight, so please, focus on the issue.

I leave the code below and some explanation about how they are composed:

**View**: It has a `TabControl` with many tabs page inside and those `TabPage`'s have controls such as: `Labels`, `TextBox`, `ComboBox` and so on.

```
public sealed partial class ProductView : ViewBase

    public ProductView(ProductViewModel viewModel) : base(viewModel) => InitializeComponent();

    public sealed async override void BindViewModel()
    {
        ProductViewModel pvm = ViewModel as ProductViewModel;
        await Task.Run(() => { while (pvm.Loading) ; });
        DataSourceUpdateMode updateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
        // Product Tab Data
        materialTextField_mpn.DataBindings.Add("Text", pvm, nameof(pvm.Product.Mpn), false, updateMode);
    }

   private void ProductView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
         (ViewModel as ProductViewModel).Load.Execute(null);
         BindViewModel();
   }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
   public sealed class ProductViewModel : ViewModelBase
   {
    private bool loading;
    private int product_id;
    private readonly IRepository<ProductModel> repository;

    private ICommand load;

    public ProductViewModel(IRepository<ProductModel> repository) => this.repository = repository;

    public ProductModel Product { get; private set; }

    private async void LoadData()
    {
        Loading = true;
        product_id = 0; // Hardcoded for testing purposes.
        Product = product_id > 0 ? await repository.GetByIdAsync(product_id) : new ProductModel()
        {
            ID = 0,
            Mpn = string.Empty
        };
        Loading = false;
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class ProductModel : ModelBase
{
    private string mpn;
     public string Mpn { 
        get => mpn;
        set
        {
            if (mpn == value)
                return;
            mpn = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(mpn));
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE & SOLUTION**

After sleeping for a while and coming back to code. I realized that the Data Binding was wrong. Excatly this line:

`materialTextField_mpn.DataBindings.Add("Text", pvm, nameof(pvm.Product.Mpn), false, updateMode);`

Just change for this one:

`materialTextField_mpn.DataBindings.Add("Text", pvm.Product, nameof(pvm.Product.Mpn), false, updateMode);`

Don't be a dummy like me lol!

Comment: It is permitted to enter your solution as an answer to your own question. This way the topic gets marked as "solved". Also, though you found your culprit, always be careful with WinForms Tab controls. The underlying Windows controls are not created (given a handle) until you display the tab page on which they are placed. This has given me a lot of headaches in the past with databinding because I was trying to databind to a control without a Handle. Cheers

Comment: Your problem was that `nameOf(pvm.Product.Mpn)`  returns just `"Mpn"`. If you provide full "path" of the property is should work without changing datasource object: `textField.DataBindings.Add("Text", pvm, "Product.Mpn", false, updateMode)` -

Comment: @LucMorin thanks for your comment, I'm new over here and like so I'm not used to StackOverflow and I don't know how to mark it as answered. Could you please tell how could I mark it already answered? Thanks!

About the other point of your answer. Absoutly I did'nt know that a `tabPage` wasn't given a handler until it was displayed. That explains why every time the application tried to show up such `tapPage` the exception was thrown.

Comment: Exactly @Fabio but I still prefer using `nameof` instead of the hardcoded property name. Because if you change the name later, you can easly change it with the IDE or the app won't simply compile until you change such property name.

Comment: @E.P. On SO, you can answer any questions you want, even your own questions. Simply take what you've added to your original post to explain how you solved the problem, and click "Add an answer", or "Post your answer". The only thing that might prevent it is if you don't have enough "reputation". I answered my own question once: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53362869/172769

Comment: @E.P. After verification, it seems you need at least 15 reputation points: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer  I'm sorry for misleading you.